# Bash : Logging a command success/failure

Tags: bash

I'm trying create a function that will log wether a command executed successfully or not.

```
function LOG_CMD() {
    "$@"
     local exit_code=$?
     if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "[$(date)]\t[SUCCESS]${@}" | sudo tee -a $LOG_FILE
      else
        echo -e "[$(date)]\t[ERROR]${@}" | sudo tee -a $LOG_FILE
     fi
}
```

This works for most commands but I'm having problems with anything that uses a pipe. For example when I try and use pipe and tee to create a config file the log entry gets written to the config.

```
LOG_CMD echo "ALTER USER '${1}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${2}';" | sudo tee -a /sql-init
```

Because I'm often writing to files the the user won't have permission to I've avoided appending to files with `>>`.

Comment: FYI -- `echo -e` is explicitly contrary to POSIX (as in, any implementation which supports it with the usage you're assuming is not just extending the standard but breaking it); the spec suggests `printf` instead -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html. (While bash supports `-e`, and thus breaks the standard, by default, it doesn't always do so; when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are set it strictly conforms).

Comment: ...on a similar portability note, consider removing the `function` keyword; simply `LOG_CMD() {` is the portable/compliant declaration syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks very much! I'll have a look at that, always looking to improve :)

Comment: BTW, since you care about the exit status of pipelines, you might want to consider enabling the `pipefail` option, to reflect a failed status if *any* component in a pipeline fails, vs the last component alone. And consider my comment on chepner's answer a reinforcement of the warning to be cautious of using `eval`.

Comment: Will do, jolly cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are not arguments; they separate two completely different commands. The only way to do what you want is to pass a single string argument to `LOG_CMD`, then use `eval` to execute it.

```
LOG_CMD() {
    eval "$1"
    local exit_code=$?
    if [ "$exit_code" -eq 0 ]; then
       result=SUCCESS
    else
       result=ERROR
    fi
    printf '[%s]\t[%s] %s\n' "$(date)" "$result" "$1" | sudo tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
}

LOG_CMD "echo \"ALTER USER '${1}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${2}';\" | sudo tee -a /sql-init"
```

Keep in mind the dangers of passing a dynamically constructed command to `eval`, however.

Comment: Using `printf %q` for variable replacements in generating the command would make this a bit safer, no? As I read this, creating a database user with `$(rm -rf $HOME)` somewhere in their password would be... let's say, unfortunate. [I mean, there's the "keep in mind the dangers" caveat, but might as well show by example how to avoid them].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes that does look like a bobby droptables situation but the circumstances this script will be used in is very controlled and I was asked to output the password despite my objections.